# Using 2 of the same type of subroutines with ABAQUS

Tags: fortran, abaqus

In an abaqus model I need to use 2 user defined loads (i.e. 2 x vdload, although this question is applicable to other subroutines).  Each vdload will act on a different set of nodes on a different part (one a line load and one a pressure load).  Creating these via cae is straightforward, but how do I code/run the subroutines to ensure each one is acting on the correct part? A challenge is that both parts will naturally have similar node numbers

Comment: Are your loads on the surface?  If so, then you can assign different surface names to your sets of nodes, then use the `sname` variable, passed in to `vdload`, to determine which load to applied.

Comment: Yes, both are surface loads - therefore this should work...thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can always apply different properties in your input file to different sections of node sets.